# Escrow Services

Tags: escrow

Can anyone recommend an honest/reliable escrow service?

With the ones I found searching the internet is that few of them are publishing their physical location so it's difficult to verify they physically exist.

Another concern is their dispute policy is lacking in detail.  My concern is what happens if the buyer claims their parcel never arrives and as the btc returned to them.  The exchange simply saying "keep evidence of posting" is lacking in detail so say the least.

Are there any escrow services in the uk?

Answer (score 1):

There's [Bitrated](https://www.bitrated.com/explore), which lets you explore a variety of independent escrow agents from the Bitcoin community. The service uses multisignature Bitcoin transactions, meaning the escrow agent has no direct control of the escrowed amount, and won't be called upon unless arbitration is requested by the other two parties. Accounts have people vouching for their authenticity, backed up with linked evidence such as social media profiles and cryptographic signatures.